# Using insertAfter() with 'this'

Tags: jquery, dom, this

I have `n` `.paymentContainer` divs for `n` number of products. For each `.paymentContainer`, I want to take the savings and put it between `<price>` and the div with class of `button`, however I continue to get an error with my jQuery statement.  Any thoughts on why my jQuery isn't working?

```js
$('div.paymentContainer').each(function() {
  $(this).children('p.savings').insertAfter($(this).children('p.pricing > price'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <price>$xxx.xx</price>
    <div class="button">add to cart</div>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <price>$xxx.xx</price>
    <div class="button">add to cart</div>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <price>$xxx.xx</price>
    <div class="button">add to cart</div>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you inventing your own element?

Comment: @j08691 not sure what you mean, I am trying to move an element.  What am I not seeing that you are?

Comment: There's no such element as `<price>`. You also seem to be unclear on how [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) works.

Comment: @j08691 consider it a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly HTML has no `<price>` element. I'd suggest using a `span` with a `price` class instead.

Secondly, you cannot have `div` elements inside a `p` as it's invalid HTML.

Lastly, in this case, you need to use `find()` to select the elements you are trying to target, because they are grandchildren of `.paymentContainer` and `children()` only looks at the child level. Try this:

```js
$('div.paymentContainer').each(function() {
  $(this).children('p.savings').insertAfter($(this).find('p.pricing > .price'))
});
```

```css
.paymentContainer {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.savings {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <span class="price">$xxx.xx</span>
    <span class="button">add to cart</span>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <span class="price">$xxx.xx</span>
    <span class="button">add to cart</span>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
<div class="paymentContainer">
  <div>some content</div>
  <p class="pricing">
    <span class="price">$xxx.xx</span>
    <span class="button">add to cart</span>
  </p>
  <p class="savings">Save $yy.yy</p>
</div>
```

With all this being said, using Javascript to re-order elements like this is not ideal. It would be better to amend the HTML source directly, if it's possible.